# Binary int to double without typecasting

Tags: c, casting, binary, microcontroller

I am doing some microcontroller programming in C. I am reading from various sensors 4 bytes that represent either `float`, `int` or `unsigned int`. Currently, I am storing them in `unsigned int` format in the microcontroller even though the data may be `float` since to a microcontroller they are just bytes. This data is then transferred to PC. I want the PC to interpret the *binary data* as a `float` or an `int` or an `unsigned int` whenever I wish. Is there a way to do that?

Ex.

```
unsigned int value = 0x40040000; // This is 2.0625 in double
double result = convert_binary_to_double(value); // result = 2.0625
```

Thanks.

PS: I tried typecasting and that does not work.

Comment: Maybe this is an endianness issue?

Comment: 32 bits is a float not double.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keeping in mind that what you're asking for isn't entirely portable, something like this will probably do the job:

```
float value = *(float *)&bits;
```

The other obvious possibility is to use a union:

```
typedef union { 
    unsigned int uint_val;
    int          int_val;
    float        float_val;
} values;

values v;
v.uint_val = 0x40040000;
float f = v.float_val;
```

Either will probably work fine, but neither guarantees portability.

Comment: Don't use the first one. See strict aliasing.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: In reality, the "strict aliasing" rules only come back to what I've said above: neither guarantees portability, but both will work with any reasonable compiler.

Comment: @Jerry The first one will result in random failures, the second one will work if the binary representations are matching.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: any compiler that screws up the first should be trashed and its authors never allowed to do their imitation of programming again.

Comment: I have been bashed a few times on SO for using a union like that.  Per the standard you cannot expect this to work but so far I have not found a compiler or situation where it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way is to cast the address of the `float` (resp `int`) to the address of an `int` (resp `float`) and to dereference that: for instance, `double result = * (float*) &value;`. Your optimizing compiler may compile this code into something that does not work as you intended though (see [strict aliasing rules](http://mail-index.netbsd.org/tech-kern/2003/08/11/0001.html)).

A way that works more often is to use an union with an `int` field and a `float` field.

Comment: Nothing like pointers that save the day. This is also a great answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do something like:
`double *x = &value;`
or a union?

Answer (score 1):

It's a terrible job :)
[this talks about their representation in memory](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) (according to the IEEE754), so with various bitwise operations you have to extract the sign, the exponent and the mantissa from your's micro controller's output, then do `number = (-1)^e * mantissa ^ (exponent - 1023)`.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by saying "type casting does not work"?
What exactly did you try?
For example, did you try something like this:

```
double convert_binary_to_double(unsigned int value)
{
    return *((double*)&value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To the PC their also just bytes, and as such could be copied into any 4 byte Int, 4 byte Unsigned Int or 4 byte Float field and the computer would be quite happy. You will need to envelope them, or somehow tag them as int, unsigned, or float. There is NO WAY the compiler can tell from looking at any 32 bit collection of bits what it's type is. - If you need a better explanation, comment me back and I'll give you the real long version - Joe
- Maybe I misunderstod you question. I thought you wanted to ship over 4 bytes of data, and have the compuuter magucly know if the data was origenally a 32 bit Int, 32 bit Unsigned or 32 bit Float. There is no way for the computer to know the answer without additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [itoa()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itoa) function? It's a neat little function often used for converting int to ASCII.